# How to move google play developer account to another google account?

Tags: android, google-play

I have a Google Play Developers account, linked my friend's Google account. We want to link it to my Google account, instead. There is any way to re-link the   Google Developers account we paid for to my email?

I tried to search on the internet, but I didn't find any solution.

I'm not sure if it is possible, but if it is possible - I will happy to get some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > **Here are steps to Move Account**

- Invite new user in an existing account
- Give him as an Admin role.
- Go with new account and revoke access from all other users from that account.
- Now You can not access app in older account.